# How to find product by 2 properties postgres

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm new in databases

I have 3 tables (columns are written for example):

- Product (id, title)
- Property (id, name, value)
- ProductProperty (product_id, property_id)

For example i have:
Product

```
 id:    title: 
 1      "Iphone 12"
 2      "Iphone 13"
 3      "Iphone 11"
```

Property

```
 id:    name:                   value:
 1      "Housing materials"     "metal"
 2      "Housing materials"     "glass"
```

ProductProperty

```
 product_id:    property_id:
 1              1
 1              2
 2              1
 2              2
 3              1
```

So, the iphone 12 and iphone 13 have two properties, but the iphone 11 have only one
How can i select all the iphones which have properties with id 1 and 2?

I just need to know how can i do that or not, or maybe someone can give me an advice how to design my database to made that kind of request?

Comment: Do you wish to select only iphones that have both props, right?

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: I want to get all products with two specific properties @Anatoly

Comment: Research GROUP BY and HAVING

Answer (score 0):

Start with Property.

Inner join to ProductProperties twice, once for each required property value.

Because inner join requires everything to be satisfied to return rows, this should only return the stuff where the product has both properties.

Finally, dedupe the result set with GROUP BY.

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.name
FROM
   Product p
-- Create a join onto ProductProperty specifically discriminating
-- on the product_id and the property_id being 1.
INNER JOIN
   ProductProperty pp1
ON p.id = pp1.product_id
AND pp1.property_id = 1
-- Then create another join, this time looking for
-- matching product_id and a product_id of 2
INNER JOIN
   ProductProperty pp2
ON p.id = pp2.product_id
AND pp2.property_id = 2
-- This *could* produce loads of rows, so ...
-- Dedupe with GROUP BY
GROUP BY
   p.id,
   p.name
```